# What is the best way to update a forked git repo/branch to have the latest upstream master?

Tags: git

The idea is that my local master is out of date from the upstream/master and I just want to get the latest changes from upstream in the most efficient way possible. I've asked around and gotten a few different answers, some of which have been:

```
git merge upstream/master
git merge --ff-only upstream/master
git branch -f master upstream/master
git rebase upstream/master master
```

I'm currently using `git merge --ff-only`, but I'm not fully aware of the pros/cons of the alternatives.

There was some clarification requested regarding forks:
Yes, this is a fork where upstream is the work of others and origin is my fork. I want to update master (locally and eventually at origin) to be the same as upstream/master.

Comment: So your current repo is a fork?

Comment: If you just want to get the changes, do `git fetch $remote`.  You only need the other commands if you also want to modify your working directory or update a local branch.

Answer (score 0):

`git pull origin master` is what i generally use

Comment: I think OPs repo is a fork and he wants the master from upstream not just his copy